# How can I isolate and extract common axios calls to prevent code duplication?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, axios

I'm trying to move a bunch of axios calls to a separate utility file so that I can share them and avoid rewriting the same or similar axios calls all over the place.

However, I can't figure out how to do this and still take advantage of the `then` and `catch` part of the call where I do unique things like updating state and/or variables.

Here is an axios call that I use and I have similar variations on this across my app:

```
axios({
  method: "post",
  url: `/api/PlanetTime/Battle/${this.props.levelId}/files/upload`,
  data: bodyFormData,
  config: {
    headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
  }
})
  .then(response => {
    let newFile = response.data[response.data.length - 1];
    this.props.onUploadEnd(response.data);
    this.setState({
      selectedFile: null,
      file: null
    });
  })
  .catch(response => {
    console.log("upload error!");
  });
```

So is there a way to have an axios call like this, yet have it be more generic, so that I can accept different urls, data, etc and still take advantage of the `then` part of the call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the `axios` call. Returning the axios call (which internally calls `axios.request` and returns a promise) would allow chainability:

```
function createRequest(url, data) {
  return axios({
    // Set up axios instance config
  });
}
```

Then, when you need it, import it:

```
createRequest('…', { … })
  .then(response => { … })
  .catch(error => { … });
```

Comment: Oh I see, so the 'then' and 'catch' parts can be in whatever component needs them?  And they would behave the same way as if I attached them directly to the axios call?

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell Yes, because you are returning the same promise from `createRequest`.

Comment: could I have it so that I could use it multiple times in one component?  Like const uploadShipPhoto = creeateRequest({...}) and then uploadWeaponPhoto = createRequest({...}) ... etc...

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell Sure. You're calling `axios` separately every time you call `createRequest`.

Comment: Can it look more es6-like by doing something like: export const createRequest = (url, data) => { axis({...}) }  ?  thanks!

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell Yes, exactly. You can just export an const assigned to an arrow function just fine, as long as you don't depend on `this` (which I don't suppose).